# XSL format-number acting weird

Tags: xslt, nan, number-formatting

I have a weird problem with the XSL number formatting function. The function will
return NaN if i do not have two elements.

I am using the XSLT version 1.0 and the libxslt XSLT processor.

Exempli gratia

This will return not a number

```
<Weight><xsl:value-of select='format-number(weight, "#.00")'/></Weight>
```

However if i do it like this

```
<Weight><xsl:value-of select='format-number(weight, "#.00")'/></Weight>
<Weight><xsl:value-of select="weight"/></Weight>
```

i get the returned values.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**

I found out that i could make PHP function calls in XSLT so i used
the PHP number_format function inorder to get the desired result.

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('number_format', weight, 2, '.', '')"/>
```

It solved my problem but it doesn't answer my question about why XSLT format-number
function is returning a NaN value.

Comment: Whixh XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: I am using XSLT version 1.0

Comment: Which XSLT processor + version are you using?

Comment: I don't know which XSL processor i am using, where can i find that information? I think the version is 1.0.

Comment: To find out which XSLT processor you are using, do `<xsl:comment>Generated using <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></xsl:comment>` which will add this information to your output file. Alternatively, tell us how you are invoking the transformation (e.g. is it in the browser? if so which browser?)

Comment: The processor i am using is libxslt and the browser is Chrome.

Comment: Can you actually your input XML here please? In particular, it would be good to see the actual **weight** element you are using. Thanks!

Comment: Well i don't want to share the code structure since i am using it for business purpose. The weight element itself arrives from a e-commerce application named Magento.